# SystemVerilog foreach syntax for looping through lower dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, system-verilog

What is the **standard** way of looping through the lower dimension of a multidimensional array? With the higher dimension fixed.

In the following example:

```
  automatic int i = 2;
  foreach (my_req[i][j]) begin // <-- WARNING
    $display("i:%0d,j:%0d", i, j);
  end
```

I see the warning:

```
** Warning: testbench.sv(16): (vlog-LRM-2897) Using non-standard foreach loop variable list syntax.
```

Full code example on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/nh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$display("Loop through i=2");
begin
  automatic int i = 2;
  foreach (my_req[,j]) begin // notice the "," before j
    $display("i:%0d,j:%0d", i, j);
  end
end
```

Working code on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Qn

Comment: @dave_59 @Tudor VCS is accepting `foreach (array[0][j])` but not accepting `automatic int h = 0; foreach (array[,j])` giving error message as Error-[NYI] Not Yet Implemented bus.sv, 318
Feature is not yet supported: Foreach with omitted loop variables preceding variable-size dimensions

Comment: Also Questa does not support this for dynamic array: Cannot omit loop variable while iterating over a dynamic array

Answer (score 4):

The warning is to let you know that the code you are writing may not be compatible with other simulators. 
I do know that at one time, another simulator accepted `foreach (array[i][j])`  where `i` was not previously defined to mean the same thing as `foreach(array[i,j])`, and that syntax would not be compatible with what you are trying to do.

The correct syntax is `foreach (my_req[,j])`

Comment: Is `foreach (array[,j])` format part of the LRM? If so, where? I could find anything mentioned. Great feature, just hope it is part of the standard.

Comment: @Greg: In 18.5.8.1, Syntax 18-7 (Foreach iterative constraint syntax), `loop_variables` can start with a comma, not necessarily an identifier:

foreach ( ps_or_hierarchical_array_identifier [ loop_variables ] ) constraint_set

loop_variables ::= [ index_variable_identifier ] { , [ index_variable_identifier ] }

Comment: Ah, I missed it because it was written in BNF (Backus-Naur Form).